# Apple's CNA screen is blocking Facebook's stylesheets

Tags: ios, css, facebook, stylesheet, captivenetwork

I just noticed that Apples Captive Network Assistant is for some reason blocking Facebook's Style Sheets.

Basically the CNA opens the page, when the user clicks to authenticate with FB we initiate the oauth flow, the FB authentication screen loads and its missing the CSS.

[FB Authentication Screen missing CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUBa9.png)

Since its CNA there is no debugging I can do in there.

Apparently, there are other few people with the same issue

[OS X CNA (Captive Network Assistant) doesn't load stylesheets for some sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40012225/os-x-cna-captive-network-assistant-doesnt-load-stylesheets-for-some-sites)